# Ubuntu on Windows: why is cd /mnt/c/Users/username/Desktop not working?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cd-command

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10. I have been able to access the directories in my desktop directly by using the `cd /mnt/c/Users/username/Desktop` command until yesterday, but today I tried accessing the directory and I keep getting an error message saying `-bash: cd: /mnt/c/Users/username/Desktop: No such file or directory'`. I clearly still have the desktop folder and I'm not sure why I'm suddenly running into this issue. I've tried running `sudo -i` before running the `cd` command but am still getting the same error. What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: Does your username contain spaces? What is the output of `ls /mnt/c/Users/username/`?

Comment: @terdon No it doesn't. The `ls` command also returns `ls: cannot access '/mnt/c/Users/username': No such file or directory`

Comment: Same question but for `/mnt/c` and `/mnt/c/Users`

Comment: Are you literally using "username" or are you substituting your actual user name?

Comment: @glennjackman I just put `username` here but yes I am using my actual user name. I also can't access /mnt/c/Users either.

Comment: "until yesterday" -- what happened yesterday? Did something get updated? What does `ls -l /mnt/c/Users` show, particularly about directory permisisons

Comment: @glennjackman I'm really not sure. I have paused my Windows from being updated automatically for many months now, and I definitely haven't updated Ubuntu either, so I'm really confused about what could have happened.

Comment: @glennjackman That also returns `ls: cannot access '/mnt/c/Users': No such file or directory

Comment: Keep going backwards. what about `/mnt/c` and `/mnt`

Comment: Is this a personal computer or is it managed by corporate IT?

Comment: @glennjackman Ok, `ls -l /mnt/c` shows `total 0` and `ls -l /mnt` shows `total 16 drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jul 11 2020 c drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jul 11 2020 f drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan 6 2021 g drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Sep 9 05:08 h drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 40 Sep 20 06:52 wsl`. I'm running these on a university-owned desktop

Comment: This looks similar: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4122 but we're at the end of my knowledge. Good luck.

Comment: @glennjackman This link helped!! I needed to shut down wsl, then restart it. Thank you so much for finding this link!